# Erro ao importar structs de um header file

Tags: c, ponteiro, struct

Preciso usar as seguintes estruturas sem alterar suas implementações de um arquivo `.h`.

```
typedef unsigned long int chave_t;
typedef unsigned long int conteudo_t;

typedef struct entrada_hash{
    chave_t chave;
    conteudo_t * conteudo;
    struct entrada_hash * proximo;
} entrada_hash_t;

typedef struct elemento_lista{
    entrada_hash_t * elemento;
    struct elemento_lista * proximo;
} elemento_lista_t;


typedef struct tabela_hash{
    unsigned long int numero_elementos;
    struct entrada_hash_t * armazenamento;                
    void * sincronizacao; 

} hash_t;
```

Porém ao inicializar a tabela hash e tentar acessar quaisqueres conteúdos colocados na sua entrada eu recebo o seguinte erro:

```
hash_s.c: In function ‘ht_init’:
hash_s.c:18:3: error: invalid use of undefined type ‘struct entrada_hash_t’
   hash->armazenamento[i]->chave = i;
   ^
hash_s.c:18:22: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type
   hash->armazenamento[i]->chave = i;
                      ^
```

A inicialização das variáveis faço da seguinte maneira:

```
hash_t * ht_init(unsigned long tam) {
    hash_t * hash ;
    unsigned long i = 0;
    hash = malloc(sizeof(hash_t));
    hash->numero_elementos = tam;
    hash->armazenamento = malloc (tam * sizeof(entrada_hash_t));
    for(i=0;i<tam;i++){
        hash->armazenamento[i]->chave = i;
    }
    return hash;
}
```

Primeiro havia pensado que as estruturas relamente não estavam sendo importadas do arquivo .h, mas se fosse assim o compilador já me daria erro ao tentar declarar as mesmas anteriormente ao `for`. Então acredito que eu não esteja atribuindo algo necessário em algum momento dentro da função `init_t`, alguém consegue perceber o que está errado?

Comment: encontrei essa resposta relacionada, https://forum.zwame.pt/threads/duvida-programacao-error-dereferencing-pointer-to-incomplete-type.493621/ mas ainda sim, não consigo encaixar no problema.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O que acontece é que quando você tem um ponteiro e pega uma posição desse ponteiro, ele deixa de ser um ponteiro e passa a ser uma variável. Em outras palavras, o ponteiro guarda o endereço de memória, quando vc passa a posição, você já está pegando o valor de dentro do ponteiro, então o `->` passa a ser `.` assim como usando em uma `struct` normal.

Assim como no exemplo abaixo:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <malloc.h>

typedef struct{
    int data;
}teste;

int caso1(){
    teste *t = (teste*) malloc(sizeof(teste));

    t->data = 5;

    printf("%d\n",t->data);
}

int caso2(){
    teste *t = (teste*) malloc(sizeof(teste));

    t[0].data = 5;

    printf("%d\n",t[0].data,);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
    caso1();
    caso2();

    return 0;
}
```

O outro erro está na declaração da variável, da struct.

```
typedef struct tabela_hash{
    unsigned long int numero_elementos;
    struct entrada_hash_t * armazenamento;                
    void * sincronizacao; 

} hash_t;
```

ele da conflito por que `entrada_hash_t` não é uma `struct`.

Para resolver isso, o campo `armazenamento` deve ser do tipo `struct entrada_hash` ou `entrada_hash_t`, que são os tipos das suas estruturas.

Comment: sim mas esse não era apenas um dos erros

Comment: @pmargreff alterei a resposta, veja se resolve o seu problema

Comment: Era isso mesmo, grato.